# Android apps doesn't sync over WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, sync, linux-mint, android, hotspot

"Network Manager" (Mint 17.1) can create a WiFi hotspot for Android phone if you use the option the «Create a Wireless Hotspot».

Until recently, this hotspot worked fine, but now i have a problem. And the problem is that the applications are not synchronized over Wifi. I just get timeout error or nothing. At the same time i can surf the internet through a browser and download/update applications through play store.

Please help me fix this problem. I'll be happy, any ideas.

**UPD**:
Sorry for my poor English. I'll try to explain what I mean.
On my desktop i have wired connection VPN(L2TP). And I want to share this connection to my android phone (Sony). I bought an adapter WiFi NETGEAR N150 WNA1100. Network Manager have button «Create a Wireless Hotspot». As I wrote above, it all worked well.

**UPD2**:
I think the phone is not a problem because I tried to connect my laptop to the same connection, and it failed. After I tried to connect the new PPA I received an error. (28, 'Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of bytes received'). But `ping google.com` it's OK.

Comment: Often a sudden problem for 'no reason' has to do with a system update or a software update. Have either your OS or your application been updated? Without more information there is not a lot to go on for anyone to assist you.

Comment: @JeffClayton yes you're right, after I upgrade the problems began (Mint 17 to 17.1). What kind of information about my system I should provide?

Comment: What to post in the future with a problem like this-- It would be important to state that it was just upgraded like you said from 17 to 17.1 and also what brand/make/model of phone and what carrier you use. It sounds like the update has a bug such as an incompatibility with your particular phone. Until they offer a bugfix, it may be necessary to roll back to version 17 instead.

Comment: What kind of application doesn't sync over wifi? Can't they sync over the internet using wifi, or should they sync via wifi (so using local ips)?

Comment: @davidbaumann As example, Pocket not sync. Also AnkiDroid not sync with message "Sync Error. Connection timed out " I have only WiFi on my phone.

Comment: Good posting your specs (+1!)

Answer (score 0):

It was my Internet service provider. They turn on firewall with smtp block. I don't know how it related? But I disable this option (block smtp) and now all my apps are synchronized.